# TDBGrid, character "ã" painted as ".." with certain regional settings

Tags: delphi, unicode, tdbgrid

Using Delphi VCL's default TDBGrid, the **ã** character is displayed as "**..**".

This only happens under certain regional settings. For example, in Portuguese or English regional settings, it displays correctly.

In Arabic regional settings however, it gets replaced with "..".

Note that the dataset's field is Unicode, as can be seen in the screenshot's TDBEdit.

Any ideas what may be going on?

Edit:
Reproducible using Delphi 10.3.1 and 10.4.2

[image]

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? How is the `ã` character being inserted into the db/grid? Did you validate the character is stored in the db correctly?

Comment: The character is inserted by typing into the TDBEdit.  The character is displayed correctly in the database manager, and the field is using UTF-8 collation. The problem only lies in the painting of the DBGrid, under certain regional settings. Reproducible under D10.3.1 and D10.4.2 (edited the question)

Comment: @tom details were already in the question. DRY, right? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out to be a font problem...

using MS Sans Serif, the character was being replaced with '..' only with specific regional settings.

changing the font to Tahoma or other, the rendering was fine regardless of regional settings.